# Why ng-bind-html shows only text without link?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using `ng-repeat` to display a list. In my data there is a field which contains **Url** that I need to be displayed as a link in my **html** page. Please see below screen shots:

**My Html:**

[image]

**My rendered page:**
[image]

I have added `angular-sanitize.js` script in my page and added dependency for '`ngSanitize`' in my main module. But I can't find why the `ng-bind-html` only showing text without link? Helps are much appreciated.

**Suggestion 1 Outcome:**
[image]

and updated code:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a hyperlink ([`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a))

```
<a href="{{ sc.url }}" ng-bind="sc.Url"></a>
```

Comment: @vpverma you using ng-bind-html but the text displayed in,   so using hyperlink will solve the problem

Comment: @GG I tried your suggestion and now it is showing link. But the problem is, the shown link is not the proper link. Please see the screen shot "Suggestion 1 Outcome:". Any idea?

Comment: Yes my bad, I edited the answer. Should work now. :)

Comment: @GG., sorry for bothering you. but I tried both `<a href="{{sc.Url}}" ng-bind-html="sc.Url"></a>` and `<a href="{{sc.Url}}" ng-bind="sc.Url"></a>` but when I hover on the links on my page (which is hosted on local IIS with name "local.puzzle.com") both of them are showing the link as **local.puzzle.com/www.google.com**, NOT only **www.google.com**.

Comment: @GG. Yap ! If `http://` is added, then both **ng-bind** and **ng-bind-html** shows the link properly. But I still didn't get the reason. Can you please explain? Also, if you update your answer, then I can mark it as **Answer**.

Comment: Well I would say that it's the normal behaviour of your browser. If your URL doesn't have a protocol (`http(s)://`), then your browser thinks it's an additional path to add to the current URL.